# Null reference exception when try to get link by class in HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-agility-pack

I have asp.net mvc application and html page which I parse using HtmlAgilityPack, but when I try looping my elements I have next error in my foreach: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. My code is next. Does anybody know where is my mistake? I'm new with using htmlagilitypack.

**Part of HTML:**

```
<li class="b-serp-item i-bem" onclick="return {&quot;b-serp-item&quot;:{}}">
  <i class="b-serp-item__favicon" style="background-position: 0 -0px"></i>
  <h2 class="b-serp-item__title">
    <b class="b-serp-item__number">1</b>
    <a class="b-serp-item__title-link" href="http://googlescraping.com/google-scraper.php">Google</a>
  </h2>
</li>
```

**CODE**

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
string dtf = String.Format("{0:u}", dt);
string wp = "page" + dtf + ".html";
HtmlDocument HD = new HtmlDocument();
HD.Load(wp);
string output = "";
foreach (HtmlNode node in HD.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='b-serp-item__title-link']"))
{
    output += node.GetAttributeValue("href", null) + " ";
}
```

Html output I was shared in google drive:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3-m-r5Ce0gOSTlzUGlTT1VBb00/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: `SelectNodes` returns `null` when it doesn't find anything,  not an empty collection as you might expect. This is why I normally add `?? new HtmlNodeCollection()`  after the call to `SelectNodes`, that way the enumeration will not throw a `NullReferenceException`. This doesn't explain why it returns no nodes though, but looking at your code, it's a likely candidate for the exception. Unless you also have `<a>` tags that have no "href" attribute...

Comment: Do you have the full HTML you're trying to parse?

Comment: @jessehouwing Yes, it's stored on the hard drive. And then I load it from the disk.

Comment: I meant for you to share the whole doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code with one slight change, I used `HtmlDocument.LoadHtml(stringContents)` instead of `HtmlDocument.Load(path)` and then it works flawlessly.

I suspect that the code is unable to find the file from the path. Ensure that the file exists using `File.Exists(wp)` and consider using a fully qualified path instead of just the file name by using `wp = Path.GetFullPath(wp)`.

Or read the contents first using `string contents = File.ReadAllText(wp);` to grab the contents and then use the `LoadHtml` method on the `HtmlDocument`.